# how to make navbar have unique url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

I am working on a site where everything is working perfectly. I have several tabs. I want each of those nav bar tabs to have an unique URL (example. www.test.com/?home). Here is the code I have now. Can someone help me to modify the code so that the tabs can have an URL?

```js
 $(".navbar-nav.systems-menu li,.systems-menu-mob li").on({
   click: function($e) {
     $e.preventDefault();
     $e.stopPropagation();

     if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;

     var curLi = $(this);
     var curName = $(this).find('a').text();
     var groupItem = $('.groups[data-group="' + curName + '"]');
     var curActive = $(".groups:visible[data-group]:not([data-template])");

     $(".systems-menu li,.systems-menu-mob li").removeClass('active');
     $(this).addClass('active');

     $(".groups:not([data-template])").eq(curActive.index()).fadeOut("normal", function() {
       var activeGroup = $(".groups:not([data-template])");
       activeGroup.eq(groupItem.index()).find(".brands-menu > li:eq(1)").addClass("active").trigger("click");
       activeGroup.eq(groupItem.index()).fadeIn("normal");
     });

     $(document).trigger("click.change-group", {
       value: curName
     });


   }


 });
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 hidden-xs" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav systems-menu" id="nav">
  </ul>
```

Comment: Hard to understand when you say *so that the tabs can have an URL?*

Comment: its like if i have four tabs : home, contact, about me, pages .. Each of the tabs can be accessed like this: www.test.com?home ,           www.test.com?contact and etc ...